# Unknown host exception Android

Tags: java, android

Mi app consume un servicio web cada que detecta una entrada a una Geocerca, pero a veces los datos móviles están apagados o están mal por la señal  y al hacer el envío manda una `UnknownHostException`, pero quisiera que cuando tenga de nuevo señal de datos o Wifi envíe esos datos al servicio web de manera automática. ¿Habrá alguna forma de hacerlo?

La conexion la estoy haciendo con `HttpUrLConnection`:

```
        URL obj;
        obj = new URL(preURL);

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
       con.setConnectTimeout(60*1*1000);
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("responseCode", "responseCode -->" + responseCode);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        if (response.toString() != null) {
            result = response.toString();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RESPUESTA=" + result);
        }

    }catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        LogFile.createLogFile(e+utils.getCurrentDate(), this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "_" + e);
        Log.v("Exepcion", "Se agoto el tiempo");
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR - (SocketTimeoutException) No Se logro enviar log...");
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        LogFile.createLogFile(utils.getCurrentDate() + e , this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "_" + e);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR - (MalformedURLException) No Se logro enviar log...");
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        LogFile.createLogFile(utils.getCurrentDate() + e, this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "_" + e);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR - (ProtocolException) No Se logro enviar log...");
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LogFile.createLogFile(utils.getCurrentDate()+e, this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "_" + e);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR - (IOException) No Se logro enviar log...");
        //Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    } finally {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "FINAL...");
    }
```

Comment: Hola @AndresLeon revisa el valor de preURL ! es incorrecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pregunta es un poco extensa, así que te resumiré como lo haría yo:

- Al capturar el UnknowHostException guardaría esos datos en alguna base de datos local, te recomiendo usar **realm**, puedes ver la documentación aquí https://realm.io/ Es bastante sencilla de usar.
- En tu objeto en el que guardas los datos de la base de datos local añadir un campo **boolean estado** para saber si ya ha sido sincronizado o no
- puedes usar este broadcast de android para saber cuando ha cambiado el estado de la conexion y enviar los datos a la base de datos.

---

```
<receiver android:name=".TURECIBIDOR">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

---

Otra manera un poco mas sencilla sería dejar un boton de sincronizar datos en tú Toolbar y enviar tu objeto de realm donde el `boolean estado = false`. También te recomiendo usar retrofit para obtener el webservice y sus posibles errores de una manera mucho mas sencilla y eficiente http://square.github.io/retrofit/ parece extenso pero en realidad te adaptas rapido

Espero que te vaya bien con todo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias :D implementare esa solucion.

Comment: ¿Esto en realidad responde a la pregunta?